# Reuse a thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to write a real time battle system for a text game. I would like the player to be able to act and have to wait a certain number of seconds before they're able to act again, while the NPC is doing the same.

I've written a small example:

```
import threading
import time

def playerattack():
    print("You attack!")
    time.sleep(2)


def npcattack():
    while hostile == True:
        print("The enemy attacks!")
        time.sleep(3)

p = threading.Thread(target=playerattack)
n = threading.Thread(target=npcattack)

hostile = False

while True:
    if hostile == True:
        n.start()
    com = input("enter 'attack' to attack:")
    if 'attack' in com:
        hostile = True
        p.start()
```

The example will work fine for the first attack:
I enter 'attack', the hostile flag is set to True, the npc attack thread starts, but I get a 'RuntimeError: threads can only be started once' when I try to attack again.

Is there a way to reuse that thread without it throwing an error? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: Yes. You are better off writing this stuff without threads.

Comment: Can you explain to a rubber duck why do you need threads for this example?

Comment: You cannot kill a thread directly in python you can however in multiprocessing which is much like threads. You are probably using threads just to learn how to use them.

Comment: When I tried to do it without threads, the time.sleep function would pause the whole program when the player/npc attacked. This meant only one entity could attack at a time.

Comment: What's wrong with turn based attacks?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with turn based, I just thought it would be really cool to have a game where different weapons had different speeds and damages. I'll look into multiprocessing though, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the thread is already running and you cannot start a running thread again because of while loop calling `n.start()` again.

Even after the thread is dead you need to reinitialize the thread instance and start again. You cannot start an old instance.

In your case in `while True` loop it is trying to start a thread multiple time. What you an do is check if thread is running, if not running start the thread instance.

```
import threading
import time

def playerattack():
    print("You attack!")
    time.sleep(2)


def npcattack():
    while hostile:
        print("The enemy attacks!")
        time.sleep(3)

p = threading.Thread(target=playerattack)
n = threading.Thread(target=npcattack)

hostile = False

while True:
    if hostile and not n.is_alive():
        try:
            n.start()
        except RuntimeError: #occurs if thread is dead
            n = threading.Thread(target=npcattack) #create new instance if thread is dead
            n.start() #start thread

    com = input("enter 'attack' to attack:")

    if 'attack' in com:
        hostile = True
        if not p.is_alive():
            try:
                p.start()
            except RuntimeError: #occurs if thread is dead
                p = threading.Thread(target=playerattack) #create new instance if thread is dead
                p.start()
```

Comment: This is perfect!
So, I wouldn't be reusing the same exact thread, I would be spawning a new thread that runs the same function. 

Thank you very much, I really appreciate it!
edit: Also, I tried to vote your answer up, and it said it recorded it but because I have less than 15 reputation it won't publicly display it. Sorry!

Comment: Yes, you cannot reuse the same thread again and again, you need to initialize a new thread instance and then run it with different variables if needed and the upvote it's not a problem.

Comment: `if hostile == True` is redundant. Just use `if hostile`.

Comment: @zondo yeah, but I wrote it to make it look clear on what is happening. Updating it though.

Answer (score 1):

We start threads with `start()` method.
After that we use `run()` method i.e `p.run()` and `n.run()` instead of `p.start()` and `n.start()` to reuse the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

I found a (hacky) way to reuse a threading.Thread object, by creating a subclass and implementing a reset method, in case you just want to change the arguments of the function that the thread is "linked" to.

```
class ReusableThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self,*args, **kwargs)
        self._default_args = self._target, self._args, self._kwargs

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().run()
        self.reset()
        
    def reset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._target = self._default_args[0]
        self._args = args or self._default_args[1]
        self._kwargs = kwargs or self._default_args[2]
```

In the python shell:

```
>>> r  = ReusableThread(target=print, args=("banana",))
>>> r.start()
banana
>>> r.reset(("banana", "apple"), "kiwi", sep='\n', end="<<<\n")
>>> r.run()
('banana', 'apple')
kiwi<<<
>>>
```